# Checkout with SVN plugin will fail when using subfolders

Tags: svn, jenkins

Jenkins somehow manages to checkout `svn://khh31046/eqdap`, where `eqdap` is a repository. But as soon as I want to checkout a subfolder of that repository by eg using `svn://khh31046/eqdap/trunk/EQ_DOSWebSample` as URL, Jenkins gives me a message saying `/trunk/EQ_DOSWebSample doesn't exist in the repository`.

I have double and triple checked this now: Checking out that URL works fine using subclipse or the commandline client. This is using

- Jenkins 1.451
- Jenkins Subversion Plug-in 1.37

Can anybody give me a hint how Jenkins does its checkouts so I can further debug the issue?

Comment: Do you have a `trunk` folder in `svn://khh31046/eqdap/trunk/EQ_DOSWebSample`?  If not, is Jenkins adding one when it goes to checkout because it looks like it adds one to get `svn://khh31046/eqdap`.

Comment: You mean like `svn://khh31046/eqdap/trunk/EQ_DOSWebSample/trunk`? No. And if I omit the folders, Jenkins feels just fine to check out the entire repository. Including the folders its complaining about when I try to specify them as checkout URL.

Comment: If SVN Server 1.7 - check [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11381)

Comment: I am indeed using SVN Server 1.7, good shot! Shame that you can't mark comments as answers.

Comment: If you'd like I can propose a workaround - it requires a bit of customization, though and has some minor problems of its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Subversion Plugin does not support Subversion 1.7](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11381)